Array issues with pine script

I am writing a strategy for pine script and I keep getting the error code like the data cannot be retrieved.
I tried to find a new string to be able to retrieve the data but there's nothing that I know of.
on line 90 I get a error code that says "Error on bar o: In 'array.get()' function. Index -1 is out of bounds, array size is zero at #main(): 90" In this line it is supposed to retrieve data to calculate the liquidity break but I keep running into that error code.
//@version=5
strategy("Market Structure Strategy with Liquidity, ChoCh, and Selectable MA", overlay=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=10)

// User Inputs
internalLength = input.int(10, title="Internal Length")
externalLength = input.int(50, title="External Length")
length_option = input.string("ALL", title="Length Option", options=["INTERNAL", "EXTERNAL", "ALL","NONE"])
swingSize_swing = input.int(5, title="Swing Size")
liquidityLengthOption = input.string("MID", title="Liquidity Length Option", options=["SHORT", "MID", "LONG"])
liquidityswingLength = input.int(30)
liquidityLength = switch liquidityLengthOption
    "SHORT" => 10
    "MID" => 28
    "LONG" => 50

// Selectable Moving Average Parameters
ma_type = input.string("SMA", title="Moving Average Type", options=["SMA", "EMA", "WMA", "VWMA"])
ma_length = input.int(20, title="Moving Average Length")

// Function to select the moving average based on user input
get_moving_average(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)
        => na  // Default to avoid errors if no type matches

// Apply the selected moving average
selected_ma = get_moving_average(close, ma_length, ma_type)

// Plot the selected moving average for visualization
plot(selected_ma, title="Selected Moving Average", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)

// Liquidity Detection Parameters
showInternalMS = (length_option == "INTERNAL" or length_option == "ALL" ) and length_option != "NONE"
showExternalMS = (length_option == "EXTERNAL" or length_option == "ALL" or length_option != "NONE")

// Adjusted Left Bars Based on Timeframe
adjustedLeftBars(tf, baseLeftBars) =>
    tf_seconds = timeframe.in_seconds(tf)
    if tf_seconds <= 60 
        10
    else if tf_seconds <= 300 
        20
    else
        baseLeftBars

leftBars = adjustedLeftBars("D", liquidityLength)  // Daily timeframe adjustment
secondLeftBars = adjustedLeftBars("W", liquidityLength)  // Weekly timeframe adjustment

// Liquidity detection variables
var highLineArrayHTF = array.new_line()
var lowLineArrayHTF  = array.new_line()
var highBoxArrayHTF  = array.new_box()
var lowBoxArrayHTF   = array.new_box()

// Persistent variables for liquidity levels
var float lastBuySideLiquidityTop = na
var float lastSellSideLiquidityBottom = na

// Detect liquidity pivots
pivotHighHTF  = ta.pivothigh(high, leftBars, leftBars)
pivotLowHTF   = ta.pivotlow(low, leftBars, leftBars)

// Populate highBoxArrayHTF and lowBoxArrayHTF when pivots are detected
if (pivotHighHTF)
    highBox = box.new(bar_index - leftBars, high[pivotHighHTF], bar_index, high)  // Create box for pivot high
    array.push(highBoxArrayHTF, highBox)

if (pivotLowHTF)
    lowBox = box.new(bar_index - leftBars, low[pivotLowHTF], bar_index, low)  // Create box for pivot low
    array.push(lowBoxArrayHTF, lowBox)

// Track Highs and Lows for ChoCh
var float recentHigh = na
var float recentLow = na

// Identify highs and lows for ChoCh
if ta.highestbars(high, swingSize_swing) == 0
    recentHigh := high
if ta.lowestbars(low, swingSize_swing) == 0
    recentLow := low

// ChoCh Conditions
chochToDowntrend = close < recentLow and ta.highestbars(low, swingSize_swing) > 0
chochToUptrend = close > recentHigh and ta.lowestbars(high, swingSize_swing) > 0

// Liquidity Break Conditions with Array Check
liquidityBreakShort = barstate.isconfirmed and array.size(highBoxArrayHTF) > 0 and close > box.get_top(array.get(highBoxArrayHTF, array.size(highBoxArrayHTF) - 1))
liquidityBreakLong = barstate.isconfirmed and array.size(lowBoxArrayHTF) > 0 and close < box.get_bottom(array.get(lowBoxArrayHTF, array.size(lowBoxArrayHTF) - 1))

// Combined Entry Conditions (including Moving Average filter)
longEntryCondition = chochToUptrend and liquidityBreakLong and close > selected_ma
shortEntryCondition = chochToDowntrend and liquidityBreakShort and close < selected_ma

// Stop Loss Levels
longStopLoss = recentLow - swingSize_swing
shortStopLoss = recentHigh + swingSize_swing

// Execute Trades
if (longEntryCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long Entry", strategy.long, stop=longStopLoss)

if (shortEntryCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short Entry", strategy.short, stop=shortStopLoss)

// Configure trail stop level with input options (optional)
longTrailPerc = input.float(3, title="Trail Long Loss (%)",
     minval=0.0, step=0.1) * 0.01

shortTrailPerc = input.float(3, title="Trail Short Loss (%)",
     minval=0.0, step=0.1) * 0.01

// Alerts for Liquidity Touch (Optional)
if barstate.isconfirmed and array.size(highBoxArrayHTF) > 0
    lastBuySideLiquidityBottom = box.get_bottom(array.get(highBoxArrayHTF, array.size(highBoxArrayHTF) - 1))
    if high >= lastBuySideLiquidityBottom
        alert("Buy-Side Liquidity Touched", alert.freq_once_per_bar)

if barstate.isconfirmed and array.size(lowBoxArrayHTF) > 0
    lastSellSideLiquidityTop = box.get_top(array.get(lowBoxArrayHTF, array.size(lowBoxArrayHTF) - 1))
    if low <= lastSellSideLiquidityTop
        alert("Sell-Side Liquidity Touched", alert.freq_once_per_bar)


Your code will be executed on each bar starting from the very first bar.
You are trying to access the elements of your array, without checking if there is anything at all in your array. And when your array is empty and you still try to access the last element, you are getting your error message.
You should always first check if your array size with an if and then try to access the elements of the array within that if block.
len = array.size(highBoxArrayHTF)

if (len > 0)
    ...

